# If $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$ and $a_n=a_{n-1} \cdot a_{n-2}+1$ for $n>1$. Are $a_{465}$ and $a_{466}$ odd or even?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$ and $a_n=a_{n-1} \cdot a_{n-2}+1$ for $n>1$. Find out whether $a_{465}$ and $a_{466}$ are odd or even.

The way I approached the problem was that Even $\times$ Even +1= Odd

Comment: Okay, but what about the other possibilities? Did you try and work out the first 10 entries of your sequence modulo 2?

Comment: So I calculated the a0 to a10 and found out that the pattern was a0 odd, a1 odd, a2 even, and the pattern continues. So every 3rd number is even and others odd. 465 is divisible by 3 and 466 gives a reminder of 1. Since the pattern started from a0 therefore I have to shift the sequence by 1 to the left and check. I got then the number should be odd and the next one should be even. But the actual answer is both the terms are odd

Answer (score 3):

The pattern goes like this

$$ odd , odd, even, odd, odd, even,....$$

Thus terms  $a_{3k+2}$ are even while other terms are odd.

Note that $465 = 3(155)$ and $466= 3(155)+1$.

As the result, $a_{465}$ and $a_{466}$ are both odd.